# AS3 - RegExp with special characters

Tags: actionscript-3, special-characters, non-latin

I'm trying to find all words with a hash in front if they are placed after the end of the sentence. 
(These ones: **#Example #FOO #hello_world #foo-bar #2012 #special-äüöå #russia-Русский #arabic-العربية**)

This is the RegExp:

```
var regex:RegExp = /#[\w\-]+?(?= #|$)/g;
```

This is the text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diamnonumy
>   eirmod tempor #invidunt ut. 
>    #Example #FOO #hello_world #foo-bar #2012 #special-äüöå #russia-Русский #arabic-العربية

It works except if special characters are included such as in **#special-äüöå #russia-Русский #arabic-العربية**

How to extend the RegExp to recognize special characters and non latin languages?

Thanks. Uli

Comment: How about changing the regex so it doesn't have to match special characters, but rather just not not match them: `/#[^ \t#]+(?=\s*#|$)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the character class `[\w\-]`, you should use `[^#]`.